# Extract different values returned in json format using GET REST call

Tags: java, json, string, rest

I am developing an application in which I am using GET REST call to get some specific nodes which return's me the nodes in the below json format:

```
[

   {

    "nodeId": "30",

    "datasetId": "2",

    "localId": "30",
    "datasetName": "Optimal Travel Route",
    "nodeName": "Location30",
    "nodeDesc": "Find the optimal travel route using travelling salesman problem  ",
    "nodeStatus": "Private",
    "gpsLat": "8.233240",
    "gpsLong": "15.029300",
    "addedBy": "internIITD",
    "addedOn": "2012-06-29 11:08:28",
    "updatedOn": "2012-06-29 11:08:28"
  }

]
```

they are no newlines .I have added here to make it readable. I am doing this to convert it to string.:

```
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                      httpCon.getInputStream()));

              String inputLine;
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(inputLine);
                      System.out.println(inputLine);
               }
              String Result;
              Result=sb.toString();
              System.out.println("result:"+Result);
```

**I want to extract the longitude and latitude of the nodes that will be given meeting specific requirements.** I am working in NetBeans 7.1.2 . I am new to JAVA.
**So , can anyone tell is there any way to extract this latitude and longitde information and store it in integer varibles.**
I used to declare JSONObject but it is not working here .I don't know why?I am not able to use JSONArray or JSONObect in my code. It is showing me an error.In the class in which I am doing this does not have a mail function. this class i.e. file has been called by some other .java file . I have multiple windows in my application.
Please help.

Comment: My complete code is in Swing Java as my making an application . Just wanted to tell by adding the tag. that the complete code is with Swing Java.

Comment: I have done that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Java should have a way of parsing JSON right? Do you get an error with that?

Comment: As I said I am new to Java. That's why I thought there might be some relationship in this , i.e, there might be some changes in the format of getting it in Swing.

Comment: @Simeon Visser when I was declaring a JSONObject it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a solution:

```
String jsonSource = /* your json string */;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonSource);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject firstObject = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
    System.out.println("Lat is:  " + firstObject.getDouble("gpsLat"));
    System.out.println("Long is: " + firstObject.getDouble("gpsLong"));
}
```

This would print:

```
Lat is:  8.23324
Long is: 15.0293
```

Comment: what should I import so that JSONArray can be used in my code?When I am using JSONArray it is giving me "cannot find symbol" JSONArray.

Comment: you should import this jar: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar Are you using eclipse? It is enough if you download this jar to local machine, and in eclipse you can right click on the project - properties - java build path - tab: libraries - add external jar. Now select the JAR you downloaded and click ok, ok, and build it again.

Comment: ok, then download the jar, right click on the project - properties - libraries - tab: compile - add JAR/Folder and select the JAR you downloaded. Click ok and rebuild it.

Comment: Yes its done. I was making a mistake.I have more than one nodes . So  how can I get all the latitude and longitude of different nodes.?I am receiving the information in the same way as I have given a example above.

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks :)! I had already excepted the answer .

Answer (score 0):

The outermost characters in that string are square brackets, so you're not dealing with a JSON object, you have a JSON array.

You said you've used `JSONObject` in other situations. [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) is for objects (which start with a `{`). Since what you have here is an array, you want to use [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead.

After creating a `JSONArray` from this string, calling `getJSONObject(0)` on it would get you a `JSONObject` for the array's first element (which is what actually contains the data in the example you've posted). Assuming the structure you posted, you'd need to do something like this:

```
JSONArray outerArray = new JSONArray(Result);
JSONObject nodeObject = outerArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

After that you can work with `nodeObject` like any other `JSONObject`.

Comment: In using JSONArray , I have to declare a JSONObject?How can I extract the values from this.the values of latitude and longitude.?

Comment: Can you please provide me a good link, or tutorial in extracting the information form this using JSONArray. I have googled a lot and I am not gettin any good tutorial for the same. Or can you explain with an example.

Comment: Have you imported `org.json.JSONArray`?

Comment: Yes I have imported this:                                            import      java.org.json.JSONArray;it is giving me an error package java.org.json does not exist.